# Certificate is not including SAN names using openssl

Tags: openssl, certificate, san

My CSR has SAN names listed but when I generate the certificate in openssl they are not being copied into the certificate.

openssl.cnf setting are:

```
[ req ]

default_bits            = 2048
default_keyfile         = privkey.pem
distinguished_name      = req_distinguished_name
attributes              = req_attributes
x509_extensions = v3_ca # The extentions to add to the self signed cert
req_extensions = v3_req

[ CA_default ]

# Extension copying option: use with caution.
copy_extensions = copy

[ v3_req ]

# Extensions to add to a certificate request
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment,dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alternate_names

[alternate_names]

DNS.1 = ocmcUmtsPn-qa.stholdco.com
DNS.2 = ocmcUmtsSsu-qa.stholdco.com
DNS.3 = ocmcCdmaPn-qa.stholdco.com
DNS.4 = ocmcCdmaPn-qa.stholdco.com
DNS.5 = ocmcMessaging-qa.stholdco.com
DNS.6 = ocmcData-qa.stholdco.com
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the command you are using to generate the CSR and perform the signing. Also, you don't want `dataEncipherment` because you don't want folks using the server's public key for bulk encryption. `digitalSignature, keyEncipherment` is fine. Related: here's the CONF file I use and the commands I use: [How do I edit a self signed certificate...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019957/how-do-i-edit-a-self-signed-certificate-created-using-openssl-xampp).

Comment: here is the command
openssl ca -out certificates/ocmcconsole-qa.pem -extensions v3_req -config ./openssl.cnf -infiles requests/ocmcconsole-qa.pem

I was grasping at straws using an example i found on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration file is nearly perfect. Your "CA_default" section has the correct `copy_extensions` setting. You only need to add these two lines, which will tell OpenSSL to use the settings in the "CA_default" section.

```
[ ca ]
default_ca      = CA_default
```

Alternatively, you can pass in a `-name CA_default` argument.