# How do I edit a self signed certificate created using openssl xampp?

Tags: openssl, xampp, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I created my own self signed certificate using openssl which is built in in xampp. However, I want to edit the common name, is this possible? Does anyone know how I can overwrite the certificate?

Answer (score 9):

> However, I want to edit the common name, is this possible? Does anyone know how I can overwrite the certificate?

Its not possible *per se*. The Common Name (CN) is in the part of the certificate that is signed, so you can't simply remove it without invalidating the signature.

However, you can simply generate a new certificate request or self-signed certificate with DNS names in the Subject Alternate Name (SAN) (and not in the Common Name (CN)).

The trick to creating a self signed certificate with DNS names in the SAN is you need to use a custom configuration file. You can't generate one using just the command line because the DNS names in the SAN are ***not*** copied. Below is the custom CONF file I use (called `example-com.conf`).

---

**example-com.conf**:

```
# Self Signed (note the addition of -x509):
#     openssl req -config example-com.conf -new -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout example-com.key.pem -days 365 -out example-com.cert.pem
# Signing Request (note the lack of -x509):
#     openssl req -config example-com.conf -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout example-com.key.pem -days 365 -out example-com.req.pem
# Print it:
#     openssl x509 -in example-com.cert.pem -text -noout
#     openssl req -in example-com.req.pem -text -noout

[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = server-key.pem
distinguished_name  = subject
req_extensions      = req_ext
x509_extensions     = x509_ext
string_mask         = utf8only

# The Subject DN can be formed using X501 or RFC 4514 (see RFC 4519 for a description).
#   Its sort of a mashup. For example, RFC 4514 does not provide emailAddress.
[ subject ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = US

stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = NY

localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default        = New York

organizationName         = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    = Example, LLC

# Use a friendly name here because its presented to the user. The server's DNS
#   names are placed in Subject Alternate Names. Plus, DNS names here is deprecated
#   by both IETF and CA/Browser Forums. If you place a DNS name here, then you 
#   must include the DNS name in the SAN too (otherwise, Chrome and others that
#   strictly follow the CA/Browser Baseline Requirements will fail).
commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default      = Example Company

emailAddress            = Email Address
emailAddress_default        = test@example.com

# Section x509_ext is used when generating a self-signed certificate. I.e., openssl req -x509 ...
[ x509_ext ]

subjectKeyIdentifier        = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid,issuer

basicConstraints        = CA:FALSE
keyUsage            = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName          = @alternate_names
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# RFC 5280, Section 4.2.1.12 makes EKU optional
# CA/Browser Baseline Requirements, Appendix (B)(3)(G) makes me confused
# extendedKeyUsage  = serverAuth, clientAuth

# Section req_ext is used when generating a certificate signing request. I.e., openssl req ...
[ req_ext ]

subjectKeyIdentifier        = hash

basicConstraints        = CA:FALSE
keyUsage            = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName          = @alternate_names
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# RFC 5280, Section 4.2.1.12 makes EKU optional
# CA/Browser Baseline Requirements, Appendix (B)(3)(G) makes me confused
# extendedKeyUsage  = serverAuth, clientAuth

[ alternate_names ]

DNS.1       = example.com
DNS.2       = www.example.com
DNS.3       = mail.example.com
DNS.4       = ftp.example.com

# Add these if you need them. But usually you don't want them or
#   need them in production. You may need them for development.
# DNS.5       = localhost
# DNS.6       = localhost.localdomain
# DNS.7       = 127.0.0.1

# IPv6 localhost
# DNS.8     = ::1
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant "edit"/change the common name of the certificate. Is it not possible to create a new one to overwrite the existing one? I was wondering whether it would just be easier to reinstall xampp and then create the certificate again..?

Comment: @fondillusions - yes, you can overwrite an existing certificate. Just ensure you change the certificate and private key in the XAMPP configuration file. There's no need to reinstall XAMPP. That's like buying a new car when it needs an oil change.

Comment: That's great, thanks! How do I change the certificate and private key in the XAMPP configuration file? Sorry, kinda a newb. I'm following the same steps again to creating a self signed certificate.. (surely that's not right?) I get an error - system library: fopen: Unknown error......

Comment: @fondillusions - see [How do I use https (SSL) in XAMPP while using virtual hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430574/how-do-i-use-https-ssl-in-xampp-while-using-virtual-hosts), [Setting up SSL on a local xampp/apache server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643462/setting-up-ssl-on-a-local-xampp-apache-server) and other related questions.